# Specific JSON Format from PHParray

Tags: php, json

I am using the below code but i need output in some of my j son format as like Excepted output Below can you please help me how i can achieve that or let me know what i am doing wrong here

```
<?php
$text = "A very nice únÌcÕdë text. Something nice to think Something about if you're into Unicode.";
$words = str_word_count($text, 1); // use this function if you only want ASCII
$frequency = array_count_values($words);
arsort($frequency);
print_r($frequency);
?>


**Current output** 
   Array
(
    [nice] => 2
    [Something] => 2
    [A] => 1
    [very] => 1
    [n] => 1
    [c] => 1
    [d] => 1
    [text] => 1
    [to] => 1
    [think] => 1
    [about] => 1
    [if] => 1
    [you're] => 1
    [into] => 1
    [Unicode] => 1
)

**Excepted output Below :**

{
    {
        ‘word’ : ‘nice’
        ‘count’ : 2
        ‘rank’ : 1
     },
    {              
        ‘word’ : ‘Something’
        ‘count’ : 2
        ‘rank’ : 2
    },
    {              
        ‘word’ : ‘A’
        ‘count’ : 1
        ‘rank’ : 3
    }
}

and so on ... etc
```

I am using the below code but i need output in some of my j son format as like Excepted output Below can you please help me how i can achieve that or let me know what i am doing wrong here

Comment: How's rank is decided?

Comment: as per count highest count 1 , 2nd highest 2 ...etc that json is for sample please consider that is correct that i just format

Comment: so us the array you got after `arsort($frequency);`. print out `$frequency` and show use the data. (Add in your question)

Comment: i updated please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I created new array with **$frequency**

```
$text = "A very nice únÌcÕdë text. Something nice to think Something about if you're into Unicode.";
$words = str_word_count($text, 1); // use this function if you only want ASCII
$frequency = array_count_values($words);
arsort($frequency);

$new_arr = array();

$rank_counter = 1;
foreach ($frequency as $key => $value) {
    $new_arr[] = array(
        'word' => $key,
        'count' => $value,
        'rank' => $rank_counter++,
    )
}

$myJSON = json_encode($new_arr);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myJSON);
```

> Output

```
[
    {
        word: "nice",
        count: 2,
        rank: 1
    },
    {
        word: "Something",
        count: 2,
        rank: 2
    },
    {
        word: "A",
        count: 1,
        rank: 3
    },
    {
        word: "very",
        count: 1,
        rank: 4
    },
    {
        word: "n",
        count: 1,
        rank: 5
    },
    {
        word: "c",
        count: 1,
        rank: 6
    },
    {
        word: "d",
        count: 1,
        rank: 7
    },
    {
        word: "text",
        count: 1,
        rank: 8
    },
    {
        word: "to",
        count: 1,
        rank: 9
    },
    {
        word: "think",
        count: 1,
        rank: 10
    },
    {
        word: "about",
        count: 1,
        rank: 11
    },
    {
        word: "if",
        count: 1,
        rank: 12
    },
    {
        word: "you're",
        count: 1,
        rank: 13
    },
    {
        word: "into",
        count: 1,
        rank: 14
    },
    {
        word: "Unicode",
        count: 1,
        rank: 15
    }
]
```

Comment: is it possible to remove 1:  2:  3 :  etc

Comment: Sorry, what do you want to remove?

Comment: one question why you create temp array what is use

Comment: temparr not necessary, we can directly make it as array. `temparr` is just for understanding. see the code i have updated.